# Reload nginx configuration on debian 7.8

Tags: nginx, configuration, webserver

I am trying to make modification in the Nginx conf.
nginx -s reload
service nginx reload
kill -HUP $PID

But new conf not working. It seems that nginx just ignored it.

nginx version: nginx/1.4.4
server: debian 7.8

Comment: Check config with `nginx -t`. I guess, you have syntax errors

Comment: Config ok, -t param check it succesfully.